# Limits; factoring: $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac {\sqrt {x+2}-2}{x-2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, factoring, radicals

$$ \lim\limits_{x \to 2} \frac { \sqrt { x + 2 } - 2 } { x - 2 } $$

I'm having so much trouble with this one

Comment: Try L'Hospital's Rule for immediate results.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we multiply this fraction by
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\sqrt{x+2}+2}{\sqrt{x+2}+2}
\end{equation}
(just another way to write 1), we have
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to 2}\dfrac{(x+2)-4}{(x-2)(\sqrt{x+2}+2)} = \lim_{x\to 2}\dfrac{x-2}{(x-2)(\sqrt{x+2}+2)} = \lim_{x\to 2}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+2}+2}.
\end{equation}
Do you see how this would help?

Comment: Yes this is perfect thanks for that answer. Stashing this in my mind for future problems.

Comment: As you probably know, this trick is called multiplying by the conjugate.  This type of limit is very popular in the early part of a first calculus course, and this trick is a useful one to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Another approach: let $$\sqrt{x+2}-2=y\implies x=(y+2)^2-2$$

As $x\to2, y\to0$

Finally as $y\to0,y\ne0$ so can be cancelled safely.

Answer (score 0):

You may notice that if $x+2>0$ then
$$x-2= (x+2)-4 = (\sqrt{x+2})^2-2^2=(\sqrt{x+2}-2)(\sqrt{x+2}+2).$$

It is basically noticing an instance of the formula $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$.

After this is should be rather straightforward how to continue.

---

You might also have a look at answers to this question, which is kind of similar: [How to evaluate this limit: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x} = \frac12$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489699/how-to-evaluate-this-limit-lim-x-to-0-frac-sqrtx1-1x-frac12)

---

It is also worth mentioning that directly from the definition of derivative you can see that this is $f'(2)$ for $f(x)=\sqrt{x+2}$.
$$f'(2)=\lim\limits_{x\to2}\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2} = 
\lim\limits_{x\to2}\frac{\sqrt{x+2}-2}{x-2}.$$
But I guess that problems like this are <s>typically</s> often assigned before you learn about derivatives. (And, moreover, you need to be able to find at least one similar limit when you are proving what derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ looks like. Once you prove that, you can of course use it, but otherwise this would lead to circular reasoning.)