# Identity to simplify $x \times \left( 1-\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x}} \right)$

Tags: asymptotics, radicals, linear-approximation, calculus

I notice that with $x \to \infty$, $x \times \left( 1-\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x}} \right) \approx 1$.

Is there any well-known identity to prove this?

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $1+\sqrt{1-2/x}$?

Comment: @Mattos Cool, it is. thanks

Comment: You are basically looking at $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+t}-1}t$. For example, here: [How to evaluate this limit: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x} = \frac12$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/489699) (Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bt%5Cto0%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B1%2Bt%7D-1%7Dt%24&p=1).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x}}}=\left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x}}\right)\times \frac{1}{1-(1-\frac{2}{x})}=\frac{x}{2}\left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x}}\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x\left(1-\sqrt{1-\dfrac{2}{x}}\right) $

$x\left(1-\sqrt{1-\dfrac{2}{x}}\right) =x-\sqrt{\dfrac{x-2}{x}} x=x-\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2 (x-2)}{x}}=$

$=x-\sqrt{x^2-2 x}=\dfrac{\left(x-\sqrt{x^2-2 x}\right) \left(x+\sqrt{x^2-2 x}\right)}{x+\sqrt{x^2-2 x}}=\dfrac{x^2-\left(x^2-2 x\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-2 x}+x}=$

$=\dfrac{2 x}{\sqrt{x^2 \left(1-\dfrac{2}{x}\right)}+x}=\dfrac{2 x}{x\sqrt{1-\dfrac{2}{x}} +x}\to \dfrac{2x}{2x}=1,\text {as }x\to\infty$